# NER features in ML Text Mining

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, named-entity-recognition

I'm doing a work in identifying fraudulent reviews, with this I'm using some feature engineering like 'NER'.

My question is, how can I fit NER into my ML algorithm? Can I vectorize it using TDF-IDF?

Also, if I'm using NER vectorized, can I still vectorize my clean text and use this?

I'm sorry if this looks a dumb question but I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.